# Find the set of real values of $p$ for which the equation $ | 2x + 3 | + | 2x - 3 | = px + 6 $ has more than two solutions .

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

[image]

Options : A ) ( 4 , 0 )

B) R-{ 4 , 0 , -4 }

C) {0}

D) None

How to find p = 0 , without having to analyse the graph ?

Comment: To see what's going on, it might help for you to graph the function $|2x + 3|  + |2x-3|$. Then see how many lines passing through $(0,6)$ intersect the graph more than twice.

Comment: @David Check details now . Updated it .

Comment: clearly p=0 has infinite number of solutions, so why the answer doesn't include p=0?

Comment: Where did you get the "answer" $\mathbb R - \{-4, 0, 4\}$?  I see $p=0$ as the only possibility to get more than two solutions in $x$.

Comment: @Macavity  Theres an option That says p = 0 . I wrote R - { -4 , 0 , 4 } cause theirs also this option and some peoples answers look like this . Truth is i dont kniw which is the correct option . It'd be good to share your work .

Answer (score 1):

let $p \in \mathbb R$, $2x-3 < 2x+3$, so if $0\leq2x-3$, $x \in [\frac{3}{2},\infty)$, the equation turns to be:
$$4x=px+6$$
this is linear equation so there is at most one solution.

if $2x+3 \leq 0 $,$x \in (-\infty,-\frac{3}{2}]$ the equation turns to be:
$$-4x=px+6$$
this is linear equation so there is at most one solution.

if $2x-3<0$ and $0 <2x+3$, $x \in [-\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}]$ we have:
$$ px=0$$

so we need $p$ such that we will have at least three solution, $0$ is always a solution,and if $p=0$, we have that the last equation has many solution(more than 3 , $x \in (-1.5,1.5)$ is a solution), so $p=0$ has more than two solutions,if $ p\neq 0$ and we have that $x=\frac{6}{(4-p)}$ and $x \in [\frac{3}{2},\infty)$ is a solution (there is one solution if $0 \leq p < 4$) and $x=-\frac{6}{(4+p)}$ and $x \in (-\infty,-\frac{3}{2}]$ (there is one solution if $-4<p\leq0$) when $p \neq 4,-4$, so we have that the set of real values $p$ that the equation has more than two solutions is $\{0\}$, the set of real valued $p$ that have two or more solutions is $(4,-4)$.

Comment: You cant say 4x = px + 6 has only one solution . for x = 2 , p = 1 , for x = 3 , p = 2 .. and so on ... and btw the answer is R - { -4 , 0 , 4 }

Comment: see question details now -

Comment: @Ricky The equation $4x=px+6$ must be considered in the unknown $x$, so it has at most one solution (because $p$ should be considered fixed).

Comment: The set of real valued $p$ that have two or more solutions is $p \in (-4, 4)$.